# What does exec("chmod +x $path; $path") do?

Tags: php, bash, shebang

I have a php code like this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path))
        {
            echo "Upload succeed !!!<br>";
            exec("chmod +x $path; $path");
            echo "Executed file !!!<br>";
            die();
        }
```

That code is part of a CTF source code. My question is: how does the `exec("chmod +x $path; $path");` work? I barely can find any manual about `exec( p1 ; p2 )`, however my guess is it execute `p1` then `p2`. Is it true? I can't make it work on my local sever using XAMPP.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that code? If you don't understand it, and can't get it to do anything, why not remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's what that means.

```
exec("chmod +x $path; $path");
```

Is basically 2 commands in one `exec`:

```
chmod +x $path
```

Change the file permissions on whatever `$path` is pointing to and add the `x` flag, which makes it executable.

```
$path
```

Now execute that file.

Comment: To clarify, `exec` sends the whole string to the shell, which sees *two* commands separated by a `;` character and therefore executes them both in turn, just as would happen if you did the same thing on the command-line.

Comment: Thanks, that really make sense to me now.